# pro*C keyword "Execute" not recognized

Tags: c, hp-ux, oracle-pro-c

I am using HP-UX aCC compiler [HP C/aC++ B3910B A.06.26] to compile an old C/Pro*C application (already compiled with an older version of aCC compiler).
The compilation is always failing with the below error

```
 Pro*C/C++: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Sun Apr 28 12:01:34 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /data/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1//precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

PCC-I-02106, Userid only used when SQLCHECK = FULL, userid ignored.
Semantic error at line 252, column 9, file ToolDb.pcpp:
        EXECUTE
........1
PCC-S-02345, SQLCHECK=SEMANTICS must be given when embedded PL/SQL blocks are us
ed
gmake: *** [ToolDb.c] Error 1
```

As I understood, the compiler cannot recognize the proc *C keyword "EXECUTE" used to call a database stored procedure!

Any idea please that can help tp solve this issue? 
Thank you very much in advance. 
Regards

Comment: Is it "Execute" (as in your title) or "EXECUTE" (as in the error message)? In any case, the error message "SQLCHECK=SEMANTICS must be given ..." probably tells you how to fix the problem. I don't know Pro*C, so I can't be sure of that. (There doesn't seem to be a tag for Pro*C, or I would have added it.)

Comment: It was a makefile issue, thnak you very much! :)

Comment: @keith oracle-pro-c is the tag

Answer (score 0):

Add `SQLCHECK=SEMANTICS` to your Proc execute command

Answer (score 0):

It is not something like Pro*C compiler is not identifying the EXECUTE command. Whenever there is error in PL/SQL block first word is displayed. 
There might be some issue inside the PL/SQL. 
It would be helpful if we can have the PL/SQL block.